# Subtrating Matrices

Tags: python

im trying to create a function where I subtract the final the values into in in a matrix. Currently, it is outputting two 1 x 2 matrixes, but I would rather it print a single 1x 2 matrix where both values are subtracted
Here is the code below

```
def testing(a, b, c):
    result1 = [a[0] // b[0][0]] + [a[1] // b[0][1] + c[0]]
    result2 = [a[0] // b[1][0]] + [a[1] // b[1][1] + c[1]]

    return result1, result2

a = [12, 5]
b = [[17, 1], [-5, 8]]
c = [53,8]

result1, result2= testing(a,b,c)
print(result1, result2) # currently it is outputting [0, 58] [-3, 8],
# is there any way to subtract the values to give [-58, -11]
```

Comment: `[-58, -11]` in place of `[0, 58]`? So your answer should be `[-58, -11], [-3, 8]`?

Comment: The above code output is [0.0, -1.1] [-2.0, 4.2] and not what you mentioned in the comment